# How to expand/collapse all blocks of ruby code in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way how to **collapse all blocks** in ruby code in Notepad++?

It is much easy to navigate the code of functions, routes in Sinatra and blocks in rufus if all blocks are collapsed.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the options under view.

The one that you are looking for is `Fold all` but you might find some of the other fold/collapse ones helpful.

Comment: The shortcut is `alt+0` for fold all and `alt+shift+0` for unfold all. Thank you.

Comment: If the shortcut is not working for you, make sure you use the 0 above the letter keys, the one on the numpad doesn't seem to work (with an AZERTY keyboard).

Comment: Or my QWERTY keyboard FYI @Stijn

Comment: This shortcurt also works for XML code.

Answer (score 25):

Short Cuts to collapse & expand :

1) To collapse/fold all blocks - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

2) To expand/unfold all blocks - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

3) To collapse current level   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

4) To expand current level     - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

The above question's superset is as follows : [Notepad++ expand/collapse block with keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/647097/notepad-expand-collapse-block-with-keyboard)

Answer (score 11):

Just to complement the answers posted before, I would like to add that it is possible to collapse the levels of nesting on a level of 1 to 8 with the following shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>[nesting level]</kbd> like so:

Nesting level 1: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Nesting level 2: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

Nesting level 3: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

Nesting level 4: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

Nesting level 5: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

Nesting level 6: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

Nesting level 7: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

Nesting level 8: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

Comment: This deserves so much more upvotes.