# Notepad++ expand/collapse block with keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

My question is pretty straight-forward, is there a way in Notepad++ to expand and collapse blocks with keyboard shortcut? I already know about the `alt+0` and `alt+shift+0` to expand / collapse all blocks but i want to achieve this for a single block.

The behavior i want to reproduce is when you click the little +/- symbol near a code or xml block but with keyboard only.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> collapse current level and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> expand it.

Comment: The shortcut alt+0 for fold all and alt+shift+0 for unfold all. http://superuser.com/questions/436023/how-to-expand-collapse-all-blocks-of-ruby-code-in-notepad

Comment: This answer is not true if you didn't select any Language from Editor and you are working with simple .txt file text blocks.

Comment: expansion is not working for me (.py file)

Comment: @joeybaruch it is working for me for .py file and I'm using v7.8.1 (64-bit). maybe you should update yours.

Comment: @user806202 how could you collapse/expand an "unknown" language? Each language does it different... brackets, spacing, etc

Answer (score 69):

In short:
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> folds (collapses) all Blocks
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> folds all Level 1
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> folds all Level 2
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> etc.

and
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> Unfolds all
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> Unfolds Level 1
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> Unfolds Level 2
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> Unfolds Level 3
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> etc.

And yes, [bzlm](https://superuser.com/users/9659/bzlm), in the ShortCut Mapper, in the Menu 'Settings', the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is mapped to a Command named `3`.
This one is below the command `Collapse Current Level`, so the meaning is `Collapse Level 3` or Fold all Level 3 Blocks

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. None of your shortcuts will expand/collapse a **single block** which is what the question asked for. This answer may be a comment on another answer, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try using <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> and for element level condense and collapse.

This will condense all siblings of the root node one by one.

Comment: I don't think **your** command does what OP described. However, it seems to do something. Care to explain what and how?

Comment: Please care. In my Notepad++ alt-3 is confusingly mapped to a command named `3`.